# If URL equals anything with this, do this?

Tags: php, url

I have a some PHP on a website that changes information based upon what the URL equals for example:

`?gw=hello` `http://mywebsite.com/?gw=hello`

Then I have this div that I would like to hide with Php kinda like this.
If `?gw=` anything then the div is hidden.

My problem is, I have no clue how I can do that. If `?gw=` is anywhere in the url, I want php to hide the div.

Hope my question makes sense! Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['gw'])) { ... don't show div  ...}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this by using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and check that `gw` is set

```
if( isset($_GET['gw'] )){
  //hide the div.
}
```

you can write like

```
if( !isset($_GET['gw'] )){
  // your div code here 
  // so if gw is set it wont include 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['gw'])){
    echo "<div>";
}
```